# unable to insert data into azure mobile services using android

Tags: android, database, azure

I try to insert data into windows azure mobile service using android apps. when i run the apps it force close. do help me out. all code, log cat error inside the zip file.

i follow the tutorial from this link:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Android-Getting-Started-With-Data-Connecting-your-app-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

Link stated below:

http://www.filedropper.com

Thanks.